# How to update a subset of 2D tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to update an index in a 2D tensor with value 0. So data is a 2D tensor whose 2nd row 2nd column index value is to be replaced by 0. However, I am getting a type error. Can anyone help me with it?

> TypeError: Input 'ref' of 'ScatterUpdate' Op requires l-value input

```
data = tf.Variable([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,0], [1,2,3,4,5]])
data2 = tf.reshape(data, [-1])
sparse_update = tf.scatter_update(data2, tf.constant([7]), tf.constant([0]))
#data = tf.reshape(data, [N,S])
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([init_op])
print "Values before:", sess.run([data])
#sess.run([updated_data_subset])
print "Values after:", sess.run([sparse_update])
```

Comment: In general, depending on how complex the updating is and on whether you plan to do this process as part of a big graph, you may want to check out `tf.py_func`, a wrapper that allows you to add numpy operations within tf graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tf.scatter_update` could only be applied to `Variable` type. `data` in your code IS a `Variable`, while `data2` IS NOT, because the return type of `tf.reshape` is `Tensor`.

Solution:

*for tensorflow after v1.0*

```
data = tf.Variable([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,0], [1,2,3,4,5]])
row = tf.gather(data, 2)
new_row = tf.concat([row[:2], tf.constant([0]), row[3:]], axis=0)
sparse_update = tf.scatter_update(data, tf.constant(2), new_row)
```

*for tensorflow before v1.0*

```
data = tf.Variable([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,0], [1,2,3,4,5]])
row = tf.gather(data, 2)
new_row = tf.concat(0, [row[:2], tf.constant([0]), row[3:]])
sparse_update = tf.scatter_update(data, tf.constant(2), new_row)
```

Comment: It does not work: ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 2
 From merging shape 1 with other shapes. for 'concat/concat_dim' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [2], [1], [2].

Comment: @AntonioSesto TensorFlow v1.0 changed some interface to keep consistent with numpy. `concat` was one of the changes. I have edited my answer to work with v1.0.

Answer (score 11):

Scatter update only works on variables. Instead try this pattern.

Tensorflow version < 1.0:

`a = tf.concat(0, [a[:i], [updated_value], a[i+1:]])`

Tensorflow version >= 1.0:

`a = tf.concat(axis=0, values=[a[:i], [updated_value], a[i+1:]])`

Comment: Extremely helpful, answering the question that should have been asked

Comment: Why doesn't tensorflow 2 have a function for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I use to modify a subset (row/column) of a 2D tensor in Tensorflow 2:

```
#note if updatedValue isVector, updatedValue should be provided in 2D format
def modifyTensorRowColumn(a, isRow, index, updatedValue, isVector):
    
    if(not isRow):
        a = tf.transpose(a)
        if(isVector):
            updatedValue = tf.transpose(updatedValue)
    
    if(index == 0):
        if(isVector):
            values = [updatedValue, a[index+1:]]
        else:
            values = [[updatedValue], a[index+1:]]
    elif(index == a.shape[0]-1):
        if(isVector):
            values = [a[:index], updatedValue]
        else:
            values = [a[:index], [updatedValue]]
    else:
        if(isVector):
            values = [a[:index], updatedValue, a[index+1:]]
        else:
            values = [a[:index], [updatedValue], a[index+1:]]
            
    a = tf.concat(axis=0, values=values)
            
    if(not isRow):
        a = tf.transpose(a)
        
    return a
```