# Modify the value of a tensor when training with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to modify the value of a tensor when I am training my model with Tensorflow.

This tensor is one of the tensors in my model

```py
weight = tf.Variable(np_matrix)
```

After some iterations, the value of `weight` will be updated automatically.

My question is: How can I modify the value of `weight` nonautomatically. I have tried this method but it didn't work.

```py
modify_weight = sess.run([weight], feed_dict = feed_dict)
modify_weight[0] = [0, 0]
weight = tf.Variable(modify_weight)
```

This part code is in `tf.Session()` section(since I want to modify the value during the training time.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like everything else, also the assignment is an operation, and we have to create a graph with the [`tf.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) and run it in a session.

So you you create an operation like this:

```
assign = tf.assign(weight, value)
```

where `value` is a `numpy` array with the same shape of `weight` (or a `tf.Placeholder` that you can modify with a feed dictionary) then you run this graph in the session:

```
sess.run(assign)
```

The `tf.Variable` also has a method `assign`, thus you can directly create the operation starting from the variable:

```
assign = weight.assign(value)
```

and than run it in a session.

Comment: Really thank you! I use `assign = weight.assign(value)` `sess.run(assign)` . But then if I don't use `new_weight = sess.run([weight], feed_dict = feed_dict)`, it still cannot modify the weight value. But now it works, thank you!